# How to make use of JSP File Creation Page in my own Wizard?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-wtp

I have a problem statement where in I need to add a page in my own wizard, the job of the page is to allow to create a JSP file with some additional tag-libs, imports.

Wizard page should ask for the valid JSP file name from user.

What I found is, eclipse already provide JSP file creation Wizard/page. Do you have any idea about what are those API ? are they extensible ? and how I can use same API in my wizard ? After loads of googling I din find any solution.

I found, same can be done for Servlets by extending "org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.internal.wizard.AddServletWizardPage" page API provided by eclipse

I also wanted to know what is IdataModel associated with JSP ?

I am very new in eclipse and have very little idea with eclipse APIs. Please help.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that it is very hard to take existing wizards like the jsp wizard, disect it, understand it and then modify it because most of these wizards are not designed to be extended and you will waste time trying to figure out detailed internals of the wizard. What I would suggest, is following the approach outlined here. [Creating New File wizard](http://www.eclipse-tips.com/how-to-guides/10-creating-new-file-wizard)

If your your new jsp file is a template and does not change based on wizard in put you can follow the same approach outlined in the link to create a text file in your bundle/plugin and load/copy it to the new resources. This wizard lets you define a constraint on file extension (in your case .jsp) and it provides pages for letting the user select the location of the file. If the initial jsp page creation is dynamic based on user input it will require some additional code on your part but going with a basic new file wizard in eclipse that is designed to be extended and then setting the file extension and setting initial file contents is the approach I would suggest instead of trying to disect and waste time in a complex wizard. In this case all you would need to do is customize the performFinish() method on the wizard to add the initial file contents. Then if you want this to show up as a wizard in file -> you use the org.eclipse.ui.wizards extension to contribute to that. If you want to have the wizard selection in its own folder you use the same extension point to create a category with an id and label and then assign the wizard to be the id of the category you created.

Hope that helps! - Duncan

Comment: Thanks Duncan, this helped a lot. Moving ahead do you have an idea about how to make use of existing JSP templates ? What I want in performFinish is to generate a JSP from a JSP template provided by eclipse.

Comment: Not sure, maybe it is as simple as finding the JSP template you want in eclipse through the JSP editor and then take that template, copy it as a text file in your plugin and then load that file in your performFinish and set contents of new resource to that template?

Comment: Found this: If you are still working on it that might be helfpul:
TemplateStore fTemplateStore = JSPUIPlugin.getDefault().getTemplateStore();
fTemplateStore.getTemplates(TemplateContextTypeIdsJSP.NEW);